# How to make Quarto Revealjs presentation text full width?

Tags: reveal.js, quarto

I am creating a Quarto Revealjs presentation. How can I make the text full width? I.e., reduce the left margin and right margin to 0?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The default margin (0.1) and width (1050) can be adjusted using [presentation size](https://quarto.org/docs/presentations/revealjs/advanced.html#presentation-size) options:

```
---
format: 
   revealjs:
     width: 3000
     margin: 0
---

## Quarto

Quarto enables you to weave together content and executable code into a finished presentation. To learn more about Quarto presentations see <https://quarto.org/docs/presentations/>. Food truck fixie locavore, accusamus mcsweeney's marfa nulla single-origin coffee squid. Exercitation +1 labore velit, blog sartorial PBR leggings next level wes anderson artisan four loko farm-to-table craft beer twee. Qui photo booth letterpress, commodo enim craft beer mlkshk aliquip jean shorts ullamco ad vinyl cillum PBR. Homo nostrud organic, assumenda labore aesthetic magna delectus mollit.
```

**Output:**

[image]